# Video software to add video effects similar to Apple's Photo Booth

Tags: video, effects

Apple Mac OS X includes Photo Booth, an application for taking photos and videos with the built-in camera (if available, of course). Photo Booth can also add effects while taking a picture or video. In the recent version (Yosemite), Photo Booth is able to detect faces and adds the effect to every face detected in the image/video, see this example I found on YouTube:

Photo Booth applies effects in real time and cannot add effects to already recorded footage.

**Is there any video editing software or video effects software available which can do this, i.e., add an effect similar to Photo Booths face detection based effects to existing video?**

Comment: You could always run a screen grab on photobooth.  Snapz Pro will let you capture video.  Or do you specifically want something different than photobooth?  There's also processing.org, but you'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonConrad: I want to apply Photo-Booth-like effects to existing videos.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the same effect after you shot the video, you could use Adobe After Effects.
Chose one of the filters under Effect>Distort. For example, let's choose Bulge.
Now you need to create keyframes so that the central point moves along with the face. You can either do this manually or use a tracker.
There are a lot of tutorials on tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Motion has a variety of distortion effects that you can apply to existing video. For example, you could use the "Poke" filter from the "Distortion" category to do something similar to the above video.